# Newbie question: What is the correct way to pass error message from ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax

The theory says:
- if there is no error, return 200
- if there is an error, return 404
but how to pass error messages with the 404 code?

I have built a backend that currently returns code 200 AND in the json response there is a 'success' flag. If the flag is false, another field contains error message.
(There may be several reasons why the operation failed and I want to display the reason to the user).

I am aware that by convention the 404 error should be returned but how can I pass the error message in that case ???

Comment: _"The theory says: - if there is no error, return 200 - if there is an error, return 404..."_ - Which theory say that?

Comment: Publish the code you are working with.

Comment: @AlonEitan - are you saying that my approach with code 200 and a 'success' flag is correct?

Comment: @Pepe Not sure what you mean - 404 error is only for specific case where the page was not fond, there are [many possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) http status codes, not just those two (200 + 404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about handling API results with these two major parts:

1. HTTP Error Responses:

   Not use this for business process errors:

   - 401 and 403 Auth and security - Describing the error cause in header
   - 404 Not found - Only when the request is about downloading file
   - and the other HTTP error status codes...
2. Business errors and failed requests:

   Responding in 200 (OK) HTTP status code and use a desired response format like this:

   - status (bool): Is True when the request is successful.
   - data: The result of API.
   - message (Object)

     - code (int [enum]): Defined by an enum describing the message type (for example model state, bad request, unavailable services, business policy, access restriction policy and so on...)
     - messages ( string[] ): The messages (like invalid fields or message[s] of process and etc...)

Comment: thanks for noticing the difference between technical error (404) and business error (200)

Answer (score 1):

If their is no error return `200`, if there is an error return `corresponding error code and message` not just `404`. `404` is received when the data or resource expected is not found.

Take a look at [HTTP Error Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

You should set the value of `error message` field based on the error that is thrown. You can either `catch` any error and set it to `error message` or you can generate your own reasons for different kinds of errors.

Your response should look like

```
{
    'success': false,
    'errorCode' : 'code', //code returned by error
    'errorMessage' : 'Custom Message' //error message     
}
```

**Note:** Post some code by editing the question so others can help you a bit better.